# django-faker install error

Tags: python, django, setuptools, django-testing

Installation of "django-faker" fails. Using either "pip" or "setup.py" directly, "distutils" fails. Other installs, including Django itself, work as expected. There are no relevant messages on the author's own site.

```
c:...\django-faker-master>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to django_faker.egg-info\requires.txt
writing django_faker.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to django_faker.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to django_faker.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'django_faker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'django_faker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
copying build\lib\django_faker\guessers.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
copying build\lib\django_faker\models.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
copying build\lib\django_faker\populator.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\templatetags
copying build\lib\django_faker\templatetags\fakers.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\templatetags
copying build\lib\django_faker\templatetags\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\templatetags
copying build\lib\django_faker\tests.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
copying build\lib\django_faker\urls.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
copying build\lib\django_faker\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\guessers.py to guessers.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\models.py to models.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\populator.py to populator.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\templatetags\fakers.py to fakers.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\templatetags\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\tests.py to tests.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\urls.py to urls.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\django_faker\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\not-zip-safe -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying django_faker.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
creating 'dist\django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg
removing 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg
Extracting django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
django-faker 0.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django_faker-0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django-faker==0.2
Searching for fake-factory>=0.2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/fake-factory/
Reading http://github.com/joke2k/faker
Best match: fake-factory 0.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/f/fake-factory/fake-factory-0.2.tar.gz#md5=e69fd4ef7a829043fe4f76533a198aa1
Processing fake-factory-0.2.tar.gz
Running fake-factory-0.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\rob\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-rjimoh\fake-factory-0.2\egg-dist-tmp-2cejrq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 43, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 76, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 104, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 427, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 478, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 563, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 799, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 811, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 62, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 105, in run
    return func()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
    'Framework :: Django'
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 28, in find_packages
    stack=[(convert_path(where), '')]
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 126, in convert_path
    raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname
ValueError: path './' cannot end with '/'
```

Comment: Could you try to reinstall `django` completely? Run `pip uninstall django; pip install django`.

Comment: if you are pulling from the development version of the package, try loading a stable version